# Call one component in various components. Angular 4

Tags: javascript, angular

Hello im using Angular 4. I have a component with some html that i want it to be showned in various components.  But when i import my module into various others moduels it says that it only can be defined in one module... how can i make it work?

i want param-var to be showned in globales and resumen.

**Console Error**

*ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: Type ParamVarComponent is part of the declarations of 2 modules: GlobalesModule and ResumenModule! Please consider moving ParamVarComponent to a higher module that imports GlobalesModule and ResumenModule. You can also create a new NgModule that exports and includes ParamVarComponent then import that NgModule in GlobalesModule and ResumenModule.*

**PARAM VAR MODULE**

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';


import { ParamVarRoutingModule } from './param-var-routing.module';
import { ParamVarComponent } from './param-var.component';

import { FormsModule, ReactiveFormsModule} from '@angular/forms';

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    ParamVarRoutingModule,
    FormsModule,
    ReactiveFormsModule
  ],
  declarations: [ParamVarComponent,

  ]
})
export class ParamVarModule { }
```

**GLOBALES MODULE**

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';


import { GlobalesRoutingModule } from './globales-routing.module';
import { GlobalesComponent } from './globales.component';

import {ParamVarComponent} from '../param-var/param-var.component';
import { FormsModule, ReactiveFormsModule} from '@angular/forms';

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    GlobalesRoutingModule,
    FormsModule,
    ReactiveFormsModule,

  ],
  declarations: [GlobalesComponent,ParamVarComponent,


  ]
})
export class GlobalesModule { }
```

**RESUMEN MODULE**

```
    import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';


import { ResumenRoutingModule } from './resumen-routing.module';
import { ResumenComponent } from './resumen.component';

import { FormsModule, ReactiveFormsModule} from '@angular/forms';
import {ParamVarComponent} from '../param-var/param-var.component';

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    ResumenRoutingModule,
    FormsModule,
    ReactiveFormsModule,

  ],
  declarations: [ResumenComponent,ParamVarComponent,


  ]
})
export class ResumenModule { }
```

Comment: can you post how you import `ParamVarModule` into other two modules?

Comment: If you create a module that declares a component, any module that import the said module will have access to that component

Comment: @BoChen check now !

Comment: @LookForAngular  look this is consoles error: 

ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: Type ParamVarComponent is part of the declarations of 2 modules: GlobalesModule and ResumenModule! Please consider moving ParamVarComponent to a higher module that imports GlobalesModule and ResumenModule. You can also create a new NgModule that exports and includes ParamVarComponent then import that NgModule in GlobalesModule and ResumenModule.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create new `SharedModule` (or any other name, but that one matches Angular's Style Guide). Declare **and export** your `ParamVarComponent` there. Now you can import `SharedModule` in any other module in your application as many times as you want. Since `ParamVarComponent` is exported, you can use it inside of other modules as soon as those modules import `SharedModule`.

```
@NgModule({
     imports: [
         CommonModule,
         FormsModule,
         ReactiveFormsModule
    ],
    declarations: [ParamVarComponent],
    exports: [ParamVarComponent]
})
export class SharedModule { }

@NgModule({
    imports: [
        CommonModule,
        FormsModule,
        ReactiveFormsModule,
        SharedModule 
    ]
})
export class OtherModule#{ }
```

Comment: Please provide an explanation not only code. @Ixam Deirf : A component can only be declared in one module at a time, in order to use the component in another module, you must export the component in the module containing it and import the module in the other module to use its exported components.

Comment: Thank you, well explained and pretty much covers the core concept of modules and exports.

Comment: THANKS, it works ! how can i make this question answerd ? where should i click ?

Comment: There should be a check mark under the up/down vote button on the left of the post. Click the check mark to mark the answer as accepted.